# 2015 Buick Encore fuel pump

Tags: fuel-system, pump

I have a 2015 Buick Encore with just shy of 26K miles and one of the fuel pumps went out. Is this normal? Should I try to trade car after fixing?

Comment: This is not normal, but it's entirely possible it was a fault with the fuel pump that GM could not have foreseen. If this is the first issue you've encountered I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: This is a fully covered repair under warranty, isn't it?  If you are happy with the car, stick with it.  Is this a four wheel drive vehicle?  If so, there should be one fuel pump, and one 'siphon' style venturi that sucks gasoline from the other side of the tank to the side with the electric fuel pump.